# Possible security concerns with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, security

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension that provides import/export functionality and I ran in to some problems when trying to implement the *Save As...* button as I could not force the download of the dynamically created JSON string using JavaScript.

I originally came up with the following JavaScript solution;

```
$('#saveAsButton').live('click', function (event) {
    var str = JSON.stringify('{}');
    window.location = 'data:text/json;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(str);
});
```

However, I cannot suggest a file name or even extension to the user for them to save it as and it relies on the mock MIME `text/json` to always require a download.

In an attempt to solve this I'm planning on creating a single PHP script on my server which, when posted to, will simply force the download of the string provided. However, my PHP knowledge (especially regarding security) isn't fantastic so I was wondering if there are any (at least obvious) security concerns with the following code;

```
<?php

$category = strtolower(urldecode($_POST['category']));
$content = urldecode($_POST['content']);

switch ($category) {
    case 'json':
        $contentType = 'text/json; charset=utf-8';
        $fileExtension = 'json';
        break;
    default:
        $contentType = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        $fileExtension = 'txt';
}

header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.' . $fileExtension);
header('Content-Type: ' . $contentType);

print $content;

?>
```

I've wrapped the *Save As...* button in a `form` element which will invoke this remote PHP code but I've modified the original listener to support "offline" mode.

```
$('#saveAsButton').live('click', function (event) {
    var str = JSON.stringify('{}'); // Simplified for purpose of example
    if (window.navigator.onLine) {
        $(this).parents('form').first().find('input[name="content"]').val(str);
    } else {
        // Fall back on "ugly" method
        window.location = 'data:text/json;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(str);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

All of the PHP and JavaScript works and I'm happy with the results so, as mentioned, I'm only really interested in any possible security vulnerabilities created by the PHP code.

Thanks in advance and I'll add further information if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only 'risk' to your script I can see is that if somebody doesn't like you, they could request the link with a large 'content' over and over again, draining your bandwidth,

You could protect against that... to some extend anyway, but I do doubt if it's gonna be an issue.

To make it more difficult though, deflate or gzip it. Makes it faster with smaller packages.

Comment: I have considered this which is why I'm pondering placing the script on a site like [Kodingen](http://kodingen.com) so that my main site is unaffected. Since it is basically limited to the size of the request (max. 2MB?) it isn't too bad but definitely should be looked at.

Comment: Also, am I correct in thinking that adding `header('Content-Encoding: gzip');` will correctly GZIP the packages?

Comment: No, you will have to actualy encode it, the easiest way I know is to use `if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")){ ob_start(); }` before the echo and `ob_flush();` afterwards

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, I'll implement this in my test immediately. I'm surprised the server doesn't do this automatically. If no one else finds any security risks I'll be sure to accept this answer.